# Why is this sap.ui.table.DataTable empty?

Tags: sapui5

I'm trying to do some stuff with the new SAPUI5 Development Kit. I found some code I want to try out but it happens that **my table is always empty**. I tried to figure it out myself but I cant do it. Here is my code:

```js
var oTable = new sap.ui.table.DataTable();
oTable.setTitle("My Table");
oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
  label: new sap.ui.commons.Label({text: "Agency Name"}),
  template: new sap.ui.commons.TextView().bindProperty("text", "NAME"),
  sortProperty: "NAME"
}));

// More Columns...
oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
  label: new sap.ui.commons.Label({text: "Currency"}),
  template: new sap.ui.commons.TextField().bindProperty("value", "CURRENCY"),
  sortProperty: "CURRENCY",
}));

var uri = "http://gw.esworkplace.sap.com/sap/opu/sdata/iwfnd/RMTSAMPLEFLIGHT";
var user = "GW@ESW";
var pw = "ESW4GW";
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel(uri,false,user,pw);
oTable.setModel(oModel);
oTable.bindRows("TravelagencyCollection");
oTable.placeAt("dataTable");
```

I tried this code in Eclipse and also on a webserver, both with the same empty table result. I found a hint to run this in chrome with the flag  `--disable-web-security` but still nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

---

Thanks for the hint. Without the flag, I get a 401 code. And with the flag, I get a 200 GET OK, but still the table is empty.

And also with `new sap.ui.commons.TextView({ text: '{key}' })`, I get an empty table.

Comment: check in chrome with the developer tools open (control-shift-i in windows) and see under 'network' if the ajax call fails. you can't do a cross domain ajax call in the browser (that's what the --disable-web-security flag is trying to solve, but the host might reject it too)

Comment: I'm not using `bindProperty` but rather the following
`new sap.ui.commons.TextView({ text: '{key}' })`. And it works for me.

Comment: I removed the ABAP tag, because the code above is definitely not ABAP. I don't know anything about SAPUI5, so although the code looks like Javascript to me at first glance, I'll leave adding the appropriate tag to someone who knows what they are doing.

Comment: @Philipp Replaced now with [sapui5] after 8 years :)

Comment: Voting to close since the majority of the mentioned modules in this question are deprecated. At the same time, there are too many issues to correct, making the question too broad to answer and less likely to help future readers.

Answer (score 0):

There could be some couple of reason

- You are making cross domain ajax request and server rejecting it to solve it try to use proxy and use tomcat server on your local or place your sapui5 code on ABAP server
- oTable.bindRows("TravelagencyCollection"); could generate bad request so use instead **oTable.bindRows("/TravelagencyCollection");**
- If both above conditions does not throwing any errors try to check whether the data from NW is coming to you or not through google developer tool(network).

Answer (score -1):

Replace

```
oTable.bindRows("TravelagencyCollection");
```

by

```
oTable.bindRows("*/*TravelagencyCollection");
```